# How to calculate superscript values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I have prices coming in my source file like below -

78-22¼,
78-18⅝

I need to calculate these price. For example for first case result should be 78-22.25. I searched a lot but found that SQL supports few of these characters only. Is there anyway to make sure we are able to calculate for whatever value we are getting. Solution in either SQL or PowerShell could work.

Comment: *"found that SQL supports few of these characters only"* this isn't true.

Comment: Ok, then can you advise how to calculate fraction values for these?

Comment: What does your question have to do with Powershell? Are you actually looking for a solution in Powershell, not SQL?

Comment: You'll need to `REPLACE` the characters to an appropriate decimal representation.

Comment: Just asking if this is not feasible in SQL and could be done in PowerShell, then I can manipulate my data in PowerShell first and then load to SQL

Comment: These are not normal fractions. these are special characters, if you copy them in your SQL you will get to know that you can't directly calculate their fraction values

Comment: `SELECT CONVERT(decimal(4,2),REPLACE(N'22¼',N'¼','.25'))` works fine for me...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249217/discussion-between-himsy-and-larnu).

Answer (score 0):

You could write a PowerShell function to convert the fractions to decimals:

```
PS ~> ConvertTo-Decimal '18⅝'
18.625
```

To do so, we'll need to write a function that:

- Uses regex to identify and extract the integer and fraction parts
- Uses `[char]::GetNumericValue()` to get the decimal representation of the fraction
- Outputs the sum of the two

```
function ConvertTo-Decimal {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$InputObject
  )

  if($InputObject -match '^(-?)(\d+)(\p{No})?$'){
    $baseValue = +$Matches[2]
    if($Matches[3]){
      $baseValue += [char]::GetNumericValue($Matches[3])
    }
    if($Matches[1] -eq '-'){
      $baseValue *= -1
    }

    return $baseValue
  }

  return 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In T-SQL you could write a function like this that takes a vulgar fraction and replaces it with its decimal equivalent (this is not completely exhaustive, but handles the most common fractions, and makes a guess about whether you want .666 or .667 or something else for ⅔):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FractionToDecimal(@str nvarchar(255))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
  RETURN 
  (
    SELECT str = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
         REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@str, N'¼','.25'),
     N'½','.5'),   N'¾','.75'),  N'⅓','.333'), N'⅔','.666'),
     N'⅛','.125'), N'⅜','.375'), N'⅝','.625'), N'⅞','.875')
  );
```

Sample usage:

```
DECLARE @x table(str nvarchar(255));
INSERT @x VALUES(N'78-22¼'),(N'78-18⅝');

SELECT [input] = i.str, [output] = o.str
   FROM @x AS i
  CROSS APPLY dbo.FractionToDecimal(str) AS o;
```

Output:

| input | output |
| --- | --- |
| 78-22¼ | 78-22.25 |
| 78-18⅝ | 78-18.625 |

Working example [in this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/P0iELlRr).

Note there are only so many fraction codes available that you could be pulling in ... so you could add any to the above [e.g. from this set](https://www.alt-codes.net/fraction-symbols) but it isn't the case that you would have to handle *any possible fraction*, only the ones that are represented by these specific symbols. If someone passes in plain text `9/10` or `31/33` that is a completely different problem space than what you have outlined in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Hoo this one was fun.

If you want to do it purley in TSQL give this a tug:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (Glyph NVARCHAR(2), Dec DECIMAL(8,6))
INSERT INTO @table (Glyph, Dec) VALUES 
(N'¼', 1.0/4),(N'½', 1.0/2),(N'¾', 3.0/4),(N'⅐', 1.0/7),
(N'⅑', 1.0/8),(N'⅒',1.0/10),(N'⅓', 1.0/3),(N'⅔', 2.0/3),
(N'⅕', 1.0/5),(N'⅖', 2.0/5),(N'⅗', 3.0/5),(N'⅘', 4.0/5),
(N'⅙', 1.0/6),(N'⅚', 5.0/6),(N'⅛', 1.0/8),(N'⅜', 3.0/8),
(N'⅝', 5.0/8),(N'⅞', 7.0/8),(N'⅟', 1.0/1)

DECLARE @values TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY, value NVARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @values (value) VALUES
(N'78-22¼'),(N'78-18⅝'),(N'10+1')

;WITH sort AS (
SELECT v.*, t.*, 
CASE WHEN m.value = v.value THEN 
     CASE WHEN t.Dec IS NOT NULL THEN REPLACE(p.value,t.Glyph,'')+dec 
          ELSE p.value 
      END 
     ELSE 
     CASE WHEN t.Dec IS NOT NULL THEN REPLACE(m.value,t.Glyph,'')+dec 
          ELSE m.value 
     END
END AS v, 
CASE WHEN m.value = v.value THEN '+' 
     ELSE '-' END AS op, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY v.value ORDER BY CASE WHEN m.value = v.value THEN CHARINDEX(m.value,v.value) ELSE CHARINDEX(p.value,v.value) END) AS subID
  FROM @values v
    OUTER APPLY STRING_SPLIT(v.value,'-') m
    OUTER APPLY STRING_SPLIT(v.value,'+') p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @table t
      ON RIGHT(CASE WHEN m.value = v.value THEN p.value ELSE m.value END,1) = t.Glyph
)

SELECT ID, value, SUM(v * CASE WHEN subId = 1 THEN 1 WHEN op = '+' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) AS v
  FROM sort
 GROUP BY ID, value
```

```
ID  value   v
---------------------
1   78-22¼  55.750000
2   78-18⅝  59.375000
3   10+1    11.000000
```

`@values` replaces your table.

disclaimer: this works, it'll probably perform like hot garbage, but it works :P